# Threading in an endless C++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a web interface where the user submits some data and it gets written to a database.  In the background there is a C++ program which periodically checks the database for new entries.  It then takes these entries, processes them  and writes their result to a directory.  It then proceeds to sleep and keep checking for new entries to process.

My question is in regards to adding multithreading to the C++ program.  I have read that it's generally a bad idea just to create a new thread every time you need a another job done, but rather add the jobs to a queue and disperse them out to a fixed number of threads that have already been created (say, 5 or so).  Is this the proper design route to take for my situation?  Also, if I understand pthread_join correctly, I don't actually need to call it because I don't want to wait for all of the jobs to finish before continuing to check for new updates to the database.

I just wanted to make sure I'm headed in the right direction, any affirmations/criticisms/resources?

Comment: pthread_join basically destroys threads. it waits until the thread returns and cleans up the thread's resources.  If your thread pool is of a fixed size and will exist forever, you will never need to join your threads.  You might consider having a cleanup plan in place in case an unrecoverable error of some sort occurs though.

Comment: @Wug Yes, that's kind of what I'm worried about. I'll have to consider when to check for such things so the whole program doesn't come crashing to a halt.

Comment: @Wug - I'd disagree, pthread_join would be necessary if you have a parent thread spawning multiple children, then waiting for them to finish execution before exiting itself. Like you said, you do want to have a cleanup plan in place, but you don't want your parent thread doing cleanup while the child threads are still handling jobs.

Comment: @Aaron i have a program that's a gps tracking platform that receives incoming calls from multiple tracking units (different models) and distributes them to threads. depending on the data protocol, it is best to add to an existing thread (especially when connection stay alive reduces network use), otherwise i dump the thread and free the system from keeping it alive (models that do not require authentication, for example).  you must take into account what are your bottlenecks and toll plazas: network time, ready accessibility (mission critical), server processing, server bandwidth - ad nauseam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first decide whether you even need more than one thread - it sounds like checking the database and writing files at some given interval can be accomplished using only one thread. Multiple threads would become useful when you start having to write different data to multiple files simultaneously at non-regular intervals. You are correct that using a queue of sorts would be the best way to distribute these 'jobs' to your threads, and that using a thread pool will give you a little more control over how many 'jobs' you want running simultaneously at any given time. The pthread_join method is used when you want to make sure one thread doesn't exit before another - I've used this mostly to make sure that the program's initial thread doesn't exit after creating the thread pool, as when the parent thread exits the program's execution stops. Some psuedo code based on my comments below.

main thread:

```
spawn child threads
while(some exit condition){
   check database for new jobs
   if(new jobs){
      acquire job queue mutex //mutexes ensures only one thread accesses shared 
      add job to queue        //data at a time
      signal on shared condition variable
      release job queue mutex 
   }
   sleep(some regular duration)
}
```

child thread:

```
while(some exit condition){
   acquire job queue mutex
   if(job queue's size == 0){
      wait on the shared condition variable
   }
   grab job from queue
   release job queue mutex
   handle job
}
```

See [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal) for pthread/mutex/CV usage notes.

Comment: Yes, the job that is being done could potentially take a while to finish, possibly 30 minutes.  So, if 5 people submit jobs at the same time, I don't want a 30 minute job to hold up a 2 minute one.  
I have a question about thread safety though.  I have a queue (right now a std::vector) of jobs, and at end of the main while loop I will iterate through the threads, find one that has nothing to do, and give it a job if one exists.  So, if I'm iterating through the threads like this, I don't have to worry about them potentially accessing the queue at the same time right?

Comment: Rather than looping through your threads and checking if they are working on something then assigning them a job from the queue if not (a form of busy waiting), you should have the threads check the queue themselves after acquiring some form of mutex. If there's no new jobs in the queue, the threads should be using a condition variable to wait on. Then when a new job enters the queue, you can signal to any waiting threads that there is work to be done. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: I'm having a little trouble imagining this, sorry.  So, I have this main infinite while loop going which reads the database and adds jobs to the queue (possibly using a mutex lock when doing so).  At the end of that particular while loop is a sleep(1), which is around where I was going to put the job checking bit.  So, if I'm going to have the threads check the queue themselves, apart from being in this loop, where would I do so?

Comment: For instance, before I start the main infinite loop, would I just assign them to a particular function which checks the queue using mutex locks?  And the condition variable would be something like queue.size > 0?

Comment: It sounds like the hard part is going to be figuring out when to 'read the database', but think of it like this - you have one thread that queries the db on a regular interval (lets say somewhere between 5-60 seconds depending on how often db gets updates). So it loops and checks database, if there's a new 'job' it acquires the queue's mutex and adds it to the queue, then signals on a condition variable, sleeps and repeats. Before it goes into this infinite loop, it spawns off N threads (your thread pool) which all acquire the mutex of the queue and check if a job is available.

Comment: If a job is available, the thread takes the job from the queue and handles it, then loops. If a job is not available, the thread waits on the condition variable. The child theads that wait on the condition variable sleep until the db thread signals on the CV that there's a new job in the queue. See my edited answer for psuedo code.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!  I have one more question: if a child thread gets the mutex of the queue, this makes it to where no other thread can do operations on the queue, correct?  So, then, how does the main thread get access to write the new job to the queue if a child thread holds the mutex?
Edit: sorry, I think my understanding of mutexes was wrong.  You mean get the handle to the mutex, not necessarily lock it right?

Comment: Of course. When one thread locks a mutex, and another thread attempts to lock the same mutex before it has been unlocked, the second thread will get put to sleep by the OS's scheduler. When the first thread unlocks the mutex, the second thread is awoken by the scheduler and is able to lock mutex. There's a lot more to it than this, but at the highest level a mutex ensures that multiple threads never read/write shared data simultaneously, but gives the threads the ability to read/write the shared data synchronously.

Comment: Ok, then I guess I still don't understand how the main thread will be able to write to the queue if one of the child threads obtains the mutex first and is waiting for the condition variable (which will only be signaled after the main thread gets the mutex itself).  Perhaps I should release the mutex from the child before waiting for the condition variable?

Comment: Sorry again, I spoke too soon.  After reading the description of using condition variables it says it releases the lock automatically:
"pthread_cond_wait() blocks the calling thread until the specified condition is signalled. This routine should be called while mutex is locked, and it will automatically release the mutex while it waits. After signal is received and thread is awakened, mutex will be automatically locked for use by the thread."

Answer (score 1):

In my experience creating a thread will most likely take tens of milliseconds. For your days computers this is not a big deal. Nothing bad will happen if it will be created/destroyed often. Looking for simple and flawless app level design might be more important.

As a possible variant, I would recommend considering a pool of threads, one thread per available CPU core. These threads should simply sleep at the end of the loop and regularly check if there is something to do or not.

This simplistic design will add minimal overhead and allow using all available CPU power at the same time.

My 2 cents.